# Would a raw icon for code sections that allows for direct download of raw code as a file be a good idea?

Tags: feature-request, code, user-interface

A lot of code websites have a little icon in code sections that allows a raw dump of the code section content. Maybe even name the file with the question ID, or some reference, so MWEs downloaded in this manner do not overwrite each other (for the people that live and breathe tex.sx - you know who you are).

This might allow for faster MWE access, depending on your desktop and editor setup and choices. Just a thought.

Comment: This reminds me of http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/821/easy-way-to-copy-code-block/891#891

Comment: There's also the potential to open the code in an online editor - see this related question: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3164/link-to-online-latex-compiler

Comment: Thanks, I guess can close this.